# Which lumberjack should I chop wood for so I get higher disposition?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I've heard that some lumberjacks will allow me to get cheaper logs if I chop wood for them. Which characters are they?

For example, will Hjorunn have a better disposition toward me if I chop wood for him?

[This wiki](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Wood_Chopping_Block) says that there is radiant option. I wonder what it is?

Comment: Please limit yourself to one question per post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Chop_Wood
That is the chop_wood wiki page, I hope this helped you!

From the wiki page:

> With the Hearthfire add-on, doing this quest for Aeri, Gilfre, Grosta, Hert, or Hod will increase their disposition such that you'll be able to cut your own lumber.

And

> Because this is a favor quest which affects the quest giver's disposition, it will count towards the "Help the People" part of the thane quest for the quest giver's hold.

Comment: Rather than just linking a page, include some of the relevant information. I'll edit in a couple details for you, as an example.

Comment: So only Aeri, Gilfre, Grosta, Hert, and Hod. What about the other lumberjacks? Any other explanation why those 5 works and the others do not?